# Как создать QML приложение, чтобы qml - файлы подгружались динамически

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Мне нужно создать небольшое QML приложение, но таким образом, чтобы qml-файлы были не в ресурсах, а в текстовом виде, чтобы я мог менять код прямо в этом файле без среды разработки, перезапускать приложение и наблюдать результат.

```
// main.qml
    import QtQuick 2.12
    import QtQuick.Window 2.12
    
    Window {
        visible: true
        width: randomInteger(200, 1900)
        height: randomInteger(200, 900)
        title: qsTr("Hello World")
        color: "yellow"
    
        function randomInteger(min, max) {
          let rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
          return Math.round(rand);
        }
    
        Loader{
               id: pageLoader
               anchors.fill: parent
               source: "Effect.qml"
           }
    }

// Effect.qml
Rectangle {
    id: shaderRect

    color: "blue"

    border.color: "green"
    border.width: 2

    anchors.fill: parent
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, это можно сделать так:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Loader{
        id: pageLoader
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "file:/e:/HomePage.qml"
    }
}
```

А на самом деле ищите лучше: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000251/load-qml-component-file-from-local-file-system

Comment: Роман, к сожалению это не работает. Что я делаю не так? Добавлю свой код

Comment: В консоли пишет qrc:/Effect.qml: No such file or directory

Comment: @ЕвгенийДружинин Проблема в том, что Вы не указываете точно где брать qml файл. По умолчанию добавляется qrc:/. С этой целью у меня в пути к файлу и указано "file:/path_to_the_file"

Comment: вы был правы, указал полный путь и всё заработало